# python pass variables with wget and check result

Tags: python, variables, wget

im so new to python im try to pass variables with Wget

code:

```
USERID = 201        
RES = os.system("wget http://localhost/ -O /usr/setting.txt")
if RES == error:
 print RES
else
 print 'good'
```

what i need to pass is

```
http://localhost/?userid=203 or username=james
```

and then read the received data

how can i achieve this?

trust me i looked at a lot of stuff posted but i'm still lost.

thank you :)

Comment: Why don't you use `urllib2.urlopen()` or the `requests` module to retrieve the URL? Do you need to store the response in a file?

Comment: @mhawke i've been asked to use **os.system**  and yes i need to save the setting to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the somewhat strange constraint that you must use `os.system()` you can construct the command string like this:

```
import os

user_id = 201    
dest_filename = '/tmp/setting.txt'
command = 'wget http://localhost/userid={} -O {}'.format(user_id, dest_filename)
res = os.system(command)
if res == 0:
    with open(dest_filename) as f:
        response = f.read()
        # process response
else:
    print('Command {!r} failed with exit code {}'.format(command, rv))
```

You can adapt the command construction to use a user name:

```
user_name = 'james'
command = 'wget http://localhost/username={} -O {}'.format(user_name, dest_filename)
```

Comment: It's not my choice :( i have to use that.

Comment: how can i use multiple variables at once? eg. userid=10&cmd=list i tried **command = 'wget http://localhost/username={}&cmd={} -O {}'.format(cmd, cmd, dest_filename)** but it don't work

Comment: That will just add `cmd` twice. Do this: `command = 'wget http://localhost/userid={}&cmd={}'.format(user_id, cmd, dest_filename)`.

Comment: But, now that you are adding multiple parameters you might be better off using [`urllib.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlencode#urllib.parse.urlencode) to construct a query string and append that to the base URL.